# Django circleci and the pillow library

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-imaging-library, circleci

Can anyone point me to why this error keeps showing up during circleci testing?

> Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image python
>   manage.py test returned exit code 1

For the record, I followed every resource I had in terms of installation instructions for pillow.

Can anyone PLEASE help me?  I'm getting desperate.

Comment: Also, how do you actually install pillow on ubuntu?  Driving me crazy.

Comment: Please contact us via the in-app help dialog so that we could take a look at your build more closely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified the Python version in your `circle.yml`? If Python version is not specified, the virtualenv might not get created for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Ubuntu, you can just type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pil
```

but if you're running in a virtualenv, you'll need to add `Pillow` to the requirements.txt file, then run

```
venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Beware that PIL has some external dependencies, [this link](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-install-pil-on-64-bit-ubuntu-1204/) explains how to solve them on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev python-dev build-essential
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
```

Comment: the part of my website that relies on pillow still won't show up.  Thoughts?